# aws organization SCP policy to deny any ec2 instances in any VPCs with public IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

With the company compliance policy, I am looking for solution to block the clients (100+ aws accounts) to create ec2 instances with public IPs or try to attach elastic IPs on it after created.

I am thinking to use [AWS Organization SCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) to implement it, so I don't need set it in individual account. But can't get the proper SCP policy to do it.

A SCP policy for your reference that I can block s3 public access with below policy, I need similar to ec2 instances.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

Idealy, with the proper SCP policy, when client in their account under Orgainzation OU, they can't create ec2 instance if they allow public IP on it, or after created the ec2, when they try to attach elastic IP, the scp should block it.

#### Updates

Thanks, @john

let me try this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AssociateAddress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### update #2

Above scp policy doesn't work, I can still create new instance with public IPs

Comment: As an alternative, perhaps only allow them to launch instances in private subnets -- even if they attach a public IP address, it will be useless. However, not sure if that is possible at an organizational level.

Comment: I got message from stackoverflow about this question has been viewed for more than thousand times, so it is a hot topic, but until now, I still don't have a nice solution for it.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I got help from AWS support.

the direction, @john targeting, is partly right, the real scp policy is as below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "BoolIfExists": {
          "ec2:AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Explanation

- The first statment blocks the clients to create new ec2 instance with Public IP ( aws ec2 run-instances --associate-public-ip-address xxxx )
- The second statement blocks the clients to attach an EIP to ec2 instances.

#### UPDATES

**This solution is not implemented finally, because it makes too much troubles.**

Especially the automation IaC codes need be adjusted for this change, such as Cloudformation, terraform, CDK, etc

I share a sample with AWS CLI and explain the change, you have to add `--no-associate-public-ip-address`

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0c9f90931dxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t3.micro \
  --key-name bill-import-key --no-associate-public-ip-address --subnet-id subnet-0613b48exxxx
```

Second, when you create ec2 instance from aws console, You have to choice `disable`  at Auto-assign Public IP .
[image]

**The solution is still the only solution to guarantee no public IP to ec2 instances in whole organisation's aws accounts, but no one likes it in the organization.**

Answer (score 1):

To block assignment of an Elastic IP address, you would deny them the `ec2:AssociateAddress` permission.

I could *not* find a `Condition` in [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-ec2_Public) for `RunInstances` that would limit the associating of a Public IP address when launching an instance (that is, the random one, as opposed to an Elastic IP address).

Comment: does that mean, it is not possible? For running instances, I can ask support team to check and action on it.  From now on, I want to apply the SCP, that no one can create new ec2 instances with public IPs.

Comment: From what I can see, it is not possible to write an IAM policy that can control allocation of a public (non-Elastic) IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The following policy statement will prevent instantiation of EC2 (runInstances) if the user choses to assign public IP. However, for this policy to be effected, the subnets should be configured to NOT assign public IP automatically.

```
{
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
    }
  },
  "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Sid": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also need to implement this, but via tag restriction. Only allow "Auto Assign Public" and EIP if a tag exists. May help you too. There's detailed description at the end of the post.

### The Policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyRunsThatHaveNoAppropriateTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "ec2:AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true"
        },
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/PublicIp": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEIPAssociationThatHaveNoAppropriateTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/PublicIp": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Explanation of the policy

You can see what resources ec2 apis touch from [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), it's important because you'll use these conditions in the policy. For example, you actually do not assign public ip directly to the ec2, it's actually assigned to an ENI, since you generally assign to the primary ENI of the ec2 instance UI may mislead you that it's actually assigned to the instance itself. Thus IAM can not refer EC2's tags for this operation.

#### `DenyRunsThatHaveNoAppropriateTag`

Only ENI have "Auto Assign Public IP" condition thus, using `*` or `arn:...eni:...` is same but for being crystal clear, I used only needed one. Each entry in `Statement[*].Condition` is AND'ed. Thus this policy means following.

Match the `ec2:RunInstances` API calls that have **both** "Auto Assign Public IP" and `PublicIp` tag is **not** equals to `true`.

Let's broke it up for didactic purposes:

- You didn't set public ip association -> IAM policy won't used
- You have set `PublicIp=true` -> IAM policy won't used
- You have `PublicIp=false` or `PublicIp=foo....` or no `PublicIp` tag at all -> IAM policy will used

When condition is met, this policy will deny that operation. Keep in mind that, even a single deny in anywhere will result into block, it doesn't matter where it's IAM role policy, resource policy, SCP...

Another interesting thing is we don't use `aws:ResourceTag` we used `aws:RequestTag` because there's no resource yet, we're trying to create it :), thus we're `Request`ing these tags.

#### DenyEIPAssociationThatHaveNoAppropriateTag

You can associate EIP with instance or ENI, thus in this resource policy, we need to give both (of course you can choose which one you want if you need).
In this case though we have the resource thus using `aws:ResourceTag` is ok.

I don't recommend using `Resource: "*"`, in practice, giving `Resource: "*"` works but you'll also need to tag each EIP itself a tag, named `PublicIp: true` which semantically bad, they're always public...

### Simple UI Tip

You can also choose ENI's tags if you want from console, it may save your time on quick demos.

[image: AWS Console EC2 Creation Tags]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help or not, but one thing I noticed about SCPs is that you are able to make exceptions for certain roles by putting that in the SCP.

I am trying to get some things setup and add a few restrictions but am hoping ( but haven't yet ) to put in some SCPs but put an exception for a superAdmin role and an automation role so they are still able to bypass the restrictions. If I get it working I'll try and post back here. This is a link to an example on AWS's site:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_general.html#example-scp-restricts-iam-principals:~:text=Prevent%20IAM%20users%20and%20roles%20from%20making%20specified%20changes%2C%20with%20an%20exception%20for%20a%20specified%20admin%20role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_general.html#example-scp-restricts-iam-principals:%7E:text=Prevent%20IAM%20users%20and%20roles%20from%20making%20specified%20changes%2C%20with%20an%20exception%20for%20a%20specified%20admin%20role)

with the details below:

**This SCP builds on the previous example to make an exception for administrators. It prevents IAM users and roles in affected accounts from making changes to a common administrative IAM role created in all accounts in your organization except for administrators using a specified role.**

```
{    
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAccessWithException",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
        "iam:DeleteRole",
        "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
        "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
        "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy",
        "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
        "iam:UpdateRole",
        "iam:UpdateRoleDescription"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/name-of-role-to-deny"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalARN":"arn:aws:iam::*:role/name-of-admin-role-to-allow"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Updated:

This did work for me at least in my case. I ended up adding the above inline policy to an existing permission set ( using AWS Organizations ) so that people who assume that permission set / role wouldn't be able to use public IP addresses. I tried to create an EC2 instnace with a public IP using that role and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

the above policy works as per expectation if applied in this way:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "ec2:AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny"
    }
  ]
}
```

by changing the `Condition` from `boolifexist` to `bool`, the SDKs are also not impacted and the cli command also work without any change